# Invalid Content Specified. Error #2048

Tags: html

I am trying to test Ooyala HTML5 Player using Google Chrome v45.0.2454.85 m. I signed in using a trial account of Ooyala and uploaded one video in the Backlot UI that has .mp4 extension.

There is one [Basic HTML5](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/reference/player_v3_dev_tutorial.html) tutorial to view the Ooyala player. I followed that tutorial but I am getting the below error when I am trying to test the webpage:-

"Invalid Content Specified. Error #2048".

I am using Tomcat as local server on my machine.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>My Test Player V3 Web Page </title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <script src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/a163e2d9a4b6427e9baad33e86d94136'></script>
    <div id='ooyalaplayer' style='width:640px;height:360px'></div>
    <script>
        OO.ready(function() {
            OO.Player.create('ooyalaplayer', 'psOWwzeDqaYbIx19WKyhGMigX7uyg_yS');
        });
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div>
            Please enable Javascript to watch this video
        </div>
    </noscript>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: just for you to know: all the tag attribute (like src, id, style) must be set with " (double quotes) and not ' (single quotes). Also you should remove the style definition from inline and move it to head section or even to a css. You have assigned an id to that div so it won't be difficult for you

Comment: That is not the problem I guess. The video is not getting played and it gives this error "Invalid Content Specified. Error #2048"

Comment: I know and I started my comment with _"just for you to know"_.  And anyway, the double quotes can be the issue. Browser can react in different way trying to understand with single quotes when it expect double

Comment: Okay!! Did all the changes, but still couldn't solve this issue.